# How to keep track of time and log data values inside of a function which is called in a loop?

Tags: python

If I import this script into another module I would like to produce a data log file with the time and distance measured. Is this possible? When the function is in a loop the log file overwrites itself and only measures the time of each loop and not the total time elapsed. Is it even possible all this inside a function that is in a loop or do I need to modify the script that imports this module. 
Here is my code:

```
def distance():
    log = open('ultrasoundlog.txt', 'w')
    log.write('Time, Distance\n')

    StartTime = time.time()
    StopTime = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO) == 0:
        StartTime = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO) == 1:
        StopTime = time.time()

    TimeElapsed = StopTime - StartTime

    distance = (TimeElapsed * 34300) / 2

    log = open('ultrasoundlog.txt', 'a')

    log.write("%f, %s\n" % ((time.time() - StartTime), (distance/100)))

    return distance

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        while True:
            dist = distance()
            print ("Measured Distance = %6.5s m" % (dist/100))
            time.sleep(0.5)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Measurement stopped by User")
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: I guess you are looking for [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr).

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.